# lookup in excel 2007 over extended range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with sorted information in the following form:

```
name      col1      col2 
AAHEIM      1         2
AAHEIM      1         2
AAHEIM      9         3
AAHEIM      7         7
AAHEIM      7         6
AMSTERDAM   1         2                 
ANTWERP     1         2     
BALTIMORE   1         2 
BARANQUILLA .         .
BARANQUILLA .         .
BARANQUILLA .         .                     
BEIRA                               
BOCA GRANDE                             
CAMPHA                              
CAPE LAMBERT                                
.
.
.
etc
```

I would like to peform a lookup such that, for example, it gives me the overall average of col1 and col2if they belong to the name "AAHEIM". In this example, the output value for col1 would be 7, and for col2 would be 4.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: ps, I am uncertain how to edit this post so as to have the information in tabulated form. Would someone be able to advise on this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A100,"AAHEIM",B1:B100)
```

where `A1:A100` is range of your names and `B1:B100` - corresponding values in `col1`. The same formula for `col2`.

If you need avarege of both columns `col1` and `col2` at the same time, use (where `B1:C100` address of columns `col1` and `col2`):

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A1:A100="AAHEIM")*(B1:C100<>""),B1:C100))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

**UPD** *Follow up from comments:*

for conditional `MAX` use this one:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A100="AAHEIM",B1:B100))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

Comment: this is excellent and answers the question perfectly! however, I found that there isn't a "maxif" function for example, nor can I perform the operation on a quartile analysis. Shall I pose this as a separate question, or should I amend my question to reflect this?

Comment: logic is the same as in my second formula: `=MAX(IF(A1:A100="AAHEIM",B1:B100))` and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate it